# 2009 Scania G360 opticruise with clutch gearbox problem

Tags: transmission, clutch, scania

I Have a euro 5 no adblue Scania G360 LA4X2HNA Opticruise with clutch. Mileage is 341931 kilometers.

The problem is that sometimes when in gear it throws out of gear. This only happens with gear 2 4 6 8 10 12.
Sometimes there is not 1 problem with the gears. When I use cruise control it throws it self out of gear. The rev go al the way up. Then I can hear a grinding in the gearbox just like putting in gear without the clutch.

I don't have this issue with gear 1 3 5 7 9 11.

Diagnose code within the dash brings up this codes:

- 13200 250times.
- 14071 250 times.

It is drivable. I just shift 1 gear down then back up. If its stays it stays. If not I just retry up down shifting.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! My first line of thinking is, I bet your clutch isn't a single clutch, but a dual clutch. One of them operating for the odd gears, one for the even. My guess is, the clutch which is for the odd gears is worn out. I can't find anything which directly tells me your truck's transmission works this way, but most "automated" manual transmissions systems are setup with multiple clutches to produce the shifting feature.

Comment: Did a research about my clutch it is a 1 plate clutch.

Comment: The error code on the internet I could find is: GMS 14071
For blocks:

1548413, 1724590, 1757823, 1763365

Title:

Upper level divider

Fault:

Loss of confirmation.

The reasons:

Elements or electrical wiring may be defective or loose connection. A mechanical fault may have occurred.

A fault code will be generated if, for example, the transmission suddenly shuts down.

Comment: I guess it is just a sensor that cant read what it suppose to read. I'm gonna try to switch the upper level divider sensor with the lower divider sensor. If the fault transfers to the lower row gears it's the sensor. If not i must look further.